# Spring Data JPA findById for updatable true columns doesn't list the column

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Data to first save and then findById from a repository.

I've explained the scenario below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table1")
@NamedQuery(name="Table1.findAll", query="SELECT s FROM Table1 s")
public class Table1 implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    @JsonIgnore
    private Table1PK id;

    @JsonProperty("userName")
    @Column(name="created_by", length=50)
    private String createdBy;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="created_date", updatable = false)

/* Other columns and getters/setters */
```

**Repository**

```
@Transactional
public interface Table1Repository extends JpaRepository<Table1, Table1PK> {

    Table1 findById(Table1PK id);

}
```

**Controller**

```
/* .... */
table1Repository.save(/*Table1*/ table1Data);
Table1 tableDataRetrieved = table1Repository.findById(/*Table1Pk*/ table1Data.getId()); //line# 1
/* .... */
```

The issue I face is the **createdDate** column get fetched as null **line#1**, and this is only when the **save** statement had an update to make.

What **updatable=false** should essentially mean is column will not be part of update statement while trying to save. But I am unclear on why it is not fetched in the output for the **findById** call.

I can although see SQL statement fired by Hibernate is correct and includes the **createdDate** column.

I have tried with saveAndFlush call as well but I still get the createdDate as null.

Any pointers.

Comment: What does the save() method do? What does table1Data contain? before you save it? Are these two lines of code inside a single transaction, or not?

Comment: # save() is the JpaRepository method. It will create a record if table1Data's primary key (composite Table1Pk) does not exist in DB, it will update otherwise.

# you can assume table1Data contains primaryKey (Id) field which exists in DB, and hence calling save will fire an update query.

# These two lines are not part of single transaction. My goal here is to retrieve the createdDate column value, regardless of whether save() performed an insert or an update. I am getting this null in both cases. If I remove "updatable=false" then I am able to retrieve it, but it's not my requirement.